# How to rollback the view style of file holder as 12.04 in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, preferences

I've upgraded the Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04. But there are something I want to change.

In 12.04, the view of file holder is as follows:

[image]

and we could open the file holder and its sub folders like this:

[image]

But in 14.04, the view style is changed into:

[image]

When I want to open the sub folder, I should click many times, especially the number of levels of sub folders is large.

So is there any way to back to the view style of file holder like 12.04? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: in the upper-right, there are a small sun, click it, and in the `Preference`, and in the third tab, click on the `view in tree view`. Then the tree goes back.